# Error: Error getting chaincode code chaincode: <go, [env]>: failed with error: "exec: not started"

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

I have created hyperledger in azure blockchain and created fabric-ca, orderer and 2 peer nodes. I am able to create channel and 2 peers joined in the channel. I am not able to install chaincode. The commands are executed form Git bash. Getting below error while running the command from peer node. Please help...

---

root@d62e3aedc701:/# peer chaincode install -n balcc -v 1.0 -p Chaincode/fabric-samples/balance-transfer/artifacts/src/github.com/example_cc/go/

2018-05-25 05:32:42.702 UTC [chaincodeCmd] checkChaincodeCmdParams -> INFO 001 Using default escc
2018-05-25 05:32:42.702 UTC [chaincodeCmd] checkChaincodeCmdParams -> INFO 002 Using default vscc
Error: Error getting chaincode code chaincode: : failed with error: "exec: not started"

---

Comment: Hey, I was wondering if you found out how to fix this. If you did, could you tell me what you did? I've got the same error.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I just reinstall go and this problem fix.